# minikube - how to access pod via pod ip using curl

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I use `minikube` to create local kubernetes cluster.

I create `ReplicationController` via `webapp-rc.yaml` file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template: 
    metadata:
      name: webapp
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: tomcat
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

and, I print the pods' ip to stdout:

`kubectl get pods -l app=webapp -o yaml | grep podIP`

```
podIP: 172.17.0.18
podIP: 172.17.0.1
```

and, I want to access pod using `curl`

`curl 172.17.0.18:8080`

But, the stdout give me: `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

I know I can access my application in docker container in pod via service.

I find this code in a book. But the book does not give the `context` for executing this code.

Using `minikube`, how to access pod via pod ip using curl in host machine?

**update 1**

I find a way using `kubectl proxy`:

```
➜  ~ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

and then I can access pod via curl like this:

`curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/webapp-jkdwz/proxy/`

`webapp-jkdwz` can be found by command `kubectl get pods -l app=webapp`

**update 2**

1. `minikube ssh` - log into minikube VM
2. and then, I can use `curl <podIP>:<podPort>`, for my case is `curl 172.17.0.18:8080`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, tomcat image expose port 8080 not 80, so the correct YAML would be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template: 
    metadata:
      name: webapp
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: tomcat
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

minikube is executed inside a virtual machine, so the curl 172.17.0.18:8080 would only work from inside that virtual machine.

You can always create a service to expose your apps:

```
kubectl expose rc webapp --type=NodePort
```

And use the following command to get the URL:

```
minikube service webapp --url
```

If you need to query a specific pod, use [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/):

```
kubectl port-forward <POD NAME> 8080
```

Or just ssh into minikube's virtual machine and query from there.

Comment: thanks. I change the tomcat expose default port. `port-forward` works fine. How do I find my minikube's VM ip and port so that I can ssh into it?

Comment: You've found it ;)   minikube ssh

Answer (score 11):

That command is correct, but it only works from a machine that has access to the overlay network. (In case of minikube the host machine does not have that by default).

You can set up a proxy to your pod with:

```
kubectl port-forward [name of your pod] [pod port]
```

Thereafter you can (from another shell):

```
curl 127.0.0.1:port/path
```

See also: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod